# Ruby Loop Countdown Method keeps returning "nil"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, rubygems, class-method

I am working on a Ruby challenge for work, and I am unable to create a working method. Every method I try keeps returning "nil".

Here is the question:

> Create a method that passes an integer argument to a single parameter. If the integer is greater than 0 print the numbers from the integer to 0. If the number is less than 0 simply print the integer. Use a for loop, while loop, or unless loop to print the range of numbers from the integer to 0.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> sample(4)    
> output = 3, 2, 1 
>
> sample(-1)    
> output  = -1
> ```

Here is the code I tried to use

```
def countdown(n)   
    loop do  
    n -= 1  
    print "#{n}"  
    break if n <= 0   
end  
countdown(4)
```

Comment: You don't use a `for`, `while`, or `unless` loop in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method returns the results of the last statement executed. Your loop is returning nil:

```
def countdown(n)   
  x = loop do  
    n -= 1  
    puts "#{n}"  
    break if n <= 0   
  end

  x
end  

countdown(4)
3
2
1
0
=> nil
```

Now let's return something:

```
def countdown(n)   
  loop do  
    puts "#{n}"  
    break if n <= 0   
    n -= 1  
  end

  "okay we're done"
end  

countdown(4)
4
3
2
1
0
=> "okay we're done"
```

Comment: This works however whenever I try to enter a negative number into the editor. Lets say countdown(-1) it returns -2. How do I edit the code so that when I enter countdown(-1) it returns -1?

Comment: @VictorMora - You just need to move the decrement step to the end. Please see edit.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to `print` inside the function and also outside it - this will cause duplicate printing. Also you are calling `print` on the positive numbers but not calling `print` if they are negative or zero. Additionally, you are using `print "#{n}"` which is the same as `print n`.

As far as the title of your question goes - "keeps returning nil" - you can change your approach a bit to do the `print` calls outside the function.

```
def countdown(n)
  n <= 1 ? [n] : (n-1).downto(1).to_a
end
print countdown(n).join(", ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def countdown(n)   
  n.downto(n > 0 ? 0 : n) { |i| puts i }
end  

countdown(4)
# 4
# 3
# 2
# 1
# 0
countdown(-4)
# -4
countdown(0)
# 0
```

You didn't mention what is to be done if the argument is zero. I've assumed it's treated as a positive or negative number.

Admittedly, this is cheating, as it does not "Use a for loop, while loop, or unless loop...", but Ruby is designed mainly to use iterators and blocks. This, or something like it, is the way to go. I just had a thought: treat that as a suggestion, not a requirement.

By the way, among loops, [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) was not mentioned, which is strange, as it is quite useful. As for "for loops", who uses them? I never have, not even once.

If you must use a loop, you could do the following.

```
def countdown(n)
  while n > 0
    puts n
    n-= 1
  end
  puts n
end

countdown(4)
# 4
# 3
# 2
# 1
# 0
countdown(-4)
# -4    
countdown(0)
# 0
```

Comment: Regarding the for loop, I guess it eases the transition for JS/Java folks. They can start with a familiar `for item in items`.

Comment: @Sergio, I say, feed them [cold turkey!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_turkey)".

Comment: How would you tackle this using a while loop?                                            `def countdown(n)     
  while    
   n -= 1    
    puts "#{n}"     
    break if n <= 1  
end  
end  

countdown(4)` This works but whenever I enter a negative number, lets say countdown(-1) it returns -2. How do I write it to countdown(-1) returns -1.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this...

```
def sample (a)
 if a > 0
    (1..a).to_a.reverse
  else
    a
  end
end
```

Hope this will work for you